# движение спрайта в разные стороны

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, pygame

В данной части моего кода, реализовано передвижение спрайта влево и вправо. Попытался на подобие сделать передвижение спрайта вниз и вверх, но программа вылетает и не работает.
Вот мой код:

```
        def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -8
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 8
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        if keystate[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.speedy = -8
        if keystate[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.speedy = 8
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
```

ошибка, я так понимаю, в данной части кода

```
        if keystate[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.speedy = -8
        if keystate[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.speedy = 8
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
```

Вот весь код, можно запустить проверить:

```
import pygame

WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 60

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Shmup!")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 40))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 10
        self.speedx = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -8
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 8
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
#        if keystate[pygame.K_DOWN]:
#            self.speedy = -8
#        if keystate[pygame.K_UP]:
#            self.speedy = 8
#        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0


all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)


running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    all_sprites.update()

    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: перепроверьте отступы в коде

Comment: предоставил минимальный воспроизводимый пример

Comment: @Jack_oS дело в том, что в том примере, в котором я добавил, если я запускаю с закоментированнами строками, всё работает. Как только строки раскоменчю, не запускается даже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допишите в `self.speedy = 0` в `__init__()`, отцентрируйте спрайт по высоте `self.rect.centery = HEIGHT / 2` и добавьте проверку на достижение края `if self.rect.top < 0` и `if self.rect.bottom > HEIGHT`:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((40, 40))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.centery = HEIGHT / 2
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0

    def update(self):
        # self.speedx = 0
        # self.speedy = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -8
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 8
        self.rect.x += self.speedx

        if keystate[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.speedy = 8
        if keystate[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.speedy = -8
        self.rect.y += self.speedy

        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

        if self.rect.top < 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
        if self.rect.bottom > HEIGHT:
            self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT
```

Comment: не-а, не работает, попытался сейчас так же сделать. Выдает ошибку в этой строке: "if self.rect.up > HEIGHT". Не нравится слово up ему

Comment: натупил, должнл быть top и bottom

Comment: получается bottom должно выглядеть так:"self.rect.bottom = WIDTH - 10"

Comment: что-то я туплю, всё равно не получается, могли бы помочь, или создать ещё одну тему с этим вопросом?

Comment: @Алексей изменил class Player в ответе, спрайт двигается во все четыре стороны и останивливается, упитаясь в край

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так:

```
import pygame

WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 60

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Shmup!")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 40))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 10
        self.speedx = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -8
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 8
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        
        if keystate[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.speedy = -8
            self.rect.y += self.speedy                  # +
        if keystate[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.speedy = 8
            self.rect.y += self.speedy                  # +
#        self.rect.y += self.speedy

        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0


all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)


running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    all_sprites.update()

    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да, получилось, спасибо!! Только теперь он может выходить за экран(сверху и снизу). Как это избежать?

Comment: @Алексей вам надо сделать проверку `HEIGHT` примерно как `WIDTH`